# How to clone multiple git repositories inside a single project in Eclipse Che?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, eclipse-che

Basically I am creating a devfile.yaml to configure Eclipse Che workspace. For example I am creating a project named "ABC" and under this project I want to clone two gitlab repos for example a.git & b.git. So, in this case  how to write the devfile.yaml to configure eclipse che workspace.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

```
Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.
```